# @twocolumnfalse seemingly has no effect

Tags: horizontal-alignment, two-column, article

I am writing a document of the type `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}`, I want to use a `pgfornament` right after the title centered. If I use it like that:

```
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
\begin{center}
test
\end{center}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
```

Where `test` is the ornament (or, it doesn't really matter, same problem when I am using the text `test`). My problem is that the `\begin{@twocolumnfalse}` doesn't do anything at all. The text or the ornament are still centered in the left column, although they should be in the center of the whole page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are just setting `\if@twocolumn` boolean to false, but as `center` (like most code) doesn't look at that boolean there is no change of behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LaTeX has a boolean flag `\if@twocolumn` which is set true if the `twocolumn` option has been used. Some code (typically `\maketitle`) checks this boolean and uses different layout in one or two column modes.

Your code fragment is equivalent to

```
{\@twocolumnfalse
\begin{center}
test
\end{center}
}
```

So it just sets the flag to false but doesn't actually change the layout. `center` does not check the boolean at all so acts as normal. In standard latex `\begin{document}`, floating environments like `figure`, `\maketitle`/`titlepage` and `abstract` are the only places that check this boolean.

---

in two column mode `article` class uses

```
          \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
```

to set the title, the optional argument here is placed in a spanning box that is full page width before the two column starts.

I would guess that your real use case should add the ornament to the definition of `\@maketitle` so that it comes *within* this spanning box.

Comment: Thank you, but is there any way to do what I need to do? I tried puting the ornament into a figure already but that doesn't help.

Comment: @luca sorry your question is far too vague for me to guess what you intended to do, I could only answer the specific question as asked as to why surrounding `center` with `@twocolumnfalse` does nothing. Probably you want to add the ornament to the definition of `\maketitle` so that it is within the spanning box that that command puts at the top of the page

Comment: @luca I'll add a note to my answer

Comment: Thanks again. I marked you answer as the solution because it would probably be enough for a normal LaTeX user but I am really new to this, could you maybe give me any pointers as to how I can `add the ornament to the definition of \@maketitle`? Because this is exactly what I need.

Comment: @luca perhaps `\makeatletter \let\old@maketitle\@maketitle  \renewcommand\@maketitle{\old@maketile\begin{center} text\end{center}}  \makeatother`

Comment: Thanks you, I couldn't quite get this to work but with some further experimentation I figured out I could use the `titling` package. Everything works fine now :)